# C# : Prevent child modal form from creating instance on taskbar

Tags: c#, modal-dialog, hide, instance

I have a parent form. When i click a button, a modal child form appeare within the form and is located at the center of the parent form :

[image: child form]

but the problem is in the taskbar, the application have 2 instances :

[image: taskbar]

How do i prevent this second instance or Hide it from the taskbar ? Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you instantiate the second form, set the [`ShowInTaskbar` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `False` to prevent it from showing up in the Windows task bar.

You don't show the code where you instantiate and display the form, but something like this should work:

```
var secondForm = new Form2
                     {
                         ShowInTaskbar = false,
                         StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
                     };

secondForm.ShowDialog();
```